# git submodule has "new commits" when I checkout master

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule called Helpers. When I clone my main project with --recursive, the Helpers submodule is in a detached head state (as all of the tutorials say it should be). If I now 'git status' in the main project directory, everything is clean. If I 'cd Helpers; git checkout master', I would expect nothing to change except that I am now on a named branch that I can commit to. However, without doing anything else, if I 'cd ..; git status', I see

```
 modified:   Helpers (new commits)
```

Why does it think there are new commits? The submodule should still be at the same point as when it was updated (in this case, cloned), no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `HEAD` of your submodule does not match the commit specified in the index of the parent repository then git will give you the "new commits" message. You can check which commit is specified in the index by running `git ls-tree`:

```
$ git ls-tree master:<path_to_folder_containing_my_submodule>
160000 commit ba9d11670daf5109a52e5a2b01bca8a344897338  my_submodule
```

When you do a recursive git clone, git will fetch the very latest and then point `HEAD` to the specified commit. If the specified commit does not match the latest commit in remote master, then `master` will not equal `HEAD` when you clone.

Another way to check after you do a recursive clone is to `cd` into your submodule and then use `git log`:

```
$ git log --decorate --all
commit 6a75034cc78fc637e2437bba9f5834835f56bd8f (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
...
commit ba9d11670daf5109a52e5a2b01bca8a344897338 (HEAD)
```

If `HEAD` and `master` point to the same commit then you can checkout master and you will not see the "new commits" message in the parent repo.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does cloning without --recursive and then doing 'cd Helpers; git submodule init; git submodule update' do anything different? Is there an easy way to get a submodule back to where the parent project says it should be, be on 'master' (so I can make commits to it), but not have fetched so that it doesn't know there is more work in the future?

Comment: A recursive clone does the same thing as submodule init & update. Any time you run a submodule update it will reset HEAD to the commit specified in the index, and any time HEAD doesn't point to that commit for any reason you'll get that message. The only way to get this message to disappear is to do a submodule update or update the commit in the index (git add <my_submodule>;git commit). You can also ignore submodules in git status with the --ignore-submodules flag (http://www.nils-haldenwang.de/frameworks-and-tools/git/how-to-ignore-changes-in-git-submodules)

Answer (score 10):

What is probably happening is that your submodule's `master` is not the version that your holding repo wants.

Set your submodule to the version that the holding repo wants:

```
holding/ $ git submodule update
```

Check the desired SHA1 of the submodule:

```
holding/ $ git submodule        # (1)
<list of all submodules, with the desired SHA1>
```

Check what your submodule's `master` is:

```
holding/ $ cd sub
holding/sub $ git checkout master
holding/sub $ git log -1     # (2)
```

Is the `SHA1` at (2) the same as what you saw at (1)? If not, that is your problem. Something happened in the submodule's master, but these new changes were not included in the holding repo.

The holding repo keeps a `SHA1` as reference to the version of the submodule to use. If further development occurs in the submodule's repo, the holding repo still keeps the same version, it does not automatically update the submodule.

If you checkout a newer version (eg `master`) of the submodule and then go back to the holding repo, `git status` will tell you that you have checked out a new commit in your submodule. This *change* of current submodule commit can be commited in your holding repo. That would update which version of the submodule is to be used with this commit of holding.

---

If you want to continue work on the submodule, from the version that the holding repo wants, you will need to create a new branch. `master` reflects further development in the submodule's repo, so either you work from `master` (and include both this further development and your new work), or you create a new branch from the detached head that holding refers to.

If you were to force `master` on the detached head that is desired by holding, what would happen to the commits (further dev) that were created between the detached head and `master`? They would be lost. And what would happen next time you push your moved `master` to `origin`? There would be a conflict since your local `master` would have diverged from `origin`'s.

Comment: How do you roll back all your submodule's to the version that your holding repo wants?  I don't care about saving any changes.  edit: it's `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: @b264 Can you actually do that if you have local changes? I'd expect git to require some kind of `force` flag if there are changes that would be lost.

Comment: It worked for me with local changes, but those local changes were the exact things I wanted undone!  `git reset --hard HEAD` does not work for submodules.